# preparedstatement batch fo insert and update?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, insert-update

i have `query = "select * from user_message  where username = 'john777@gmail.com';"` . There is a  column 'is_read'( When  message is sent to user , is_read is false by default , it means user has not read message yet),  after  first selection i have to change  that column to true `UPDATE user_message
   SET is_read=true where username = 'john777@gmail.com';`  Which means user has read message . so question is can i  make one query and  execute it throught batch  or should i make two different queries ?   Which way is better ?

Comment: you can loop over the values that you want to update using a single preparedStatement by only setting the parameters every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are write one method with two parameters username and is_read. You can call this method any-time when you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your update statement is incorrect since it doesn't pass a message id

I'm guessing it's something like:

```
UPDATE user_message
SET is_read=true 
where username = 'john777@gmail.com'
and user_message_id = 123
```

If you'd like to set multiple messages to `read` you could do this via:

```
UPDATE user_message
SET is_read=true 
where username = 'john777@gmail.com'
and user_message_id in (123, 234, 456)
```

This feels like a design flaw to me. Why does the user_message table have the email? What happens if the user changes their email? You should really decouple the email from the user by giving each user a unique (integer) id which you use as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption the you have a `Collection` of parameters say `emails`, I would suggest the following:

```
String sql = "Your statement";
PreparedStatement stmt = conection.prepare(sql);
for(String email : emails){
   stmt.setString(1, email);
   stmt.executeUpdate();
   stmt.clearParameters();
}
```

This I think will help you.